# Using doxygen with avr-gcc variable types

Tags: variables, doxygen, avr-gcc

I want to use doxygen for my microcontroller projects with avr-gcc.
Doxygen is working good as expected, but i have a problem with the variables.

In avr-gcc special variable types are used that are not recognized by doxygen. Like in this example:

```
static uint8_t  timeout;        ///< timeout counter
static uint16_t  bootcount;     ///< boot counter
volatile uint8_t  seconds;      ///< system time seconds
volatile uint8_t  minutes;      ///< system time minutes

uint32_t EE_lifetime EEMEM = 0; ///< overall time in use
uint8_t  EE_dummy EEMEM = 0xFF; ///< http://www.atmel.com/webdoc/AVRLibcReferenceManual/FAQ_1faq_eeprom_corruption.html
```

When i run doxygen only the volatile variables are listed correct, all other global variables are ignored.

The variables in EEPROM  are completely messed up, because in the overview only the first variable is listed and the rest is missing.
In the detail view only EE_dummy is listed but with the comments of all EEPROM variables.

The variable types are defined in /usr/lib/avr/include/stdint.h
http://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/group__avr__stdint.html

In Doxyfile the settings should be correct:

```
SEARCH_INCLUDES = YES
ENABLE_PREPROCESSING = YES
```

I could not find out what is wrong or missing?

Some time ago there was a similar question, that was not answered.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34796928/doxygen-uint8-t-and-other-stdint-h-inttypes-h-integer-types

[Result in the browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gHTAY.png)

Comment: Regarding the static variables, check the setting of EXTRACT_STATIC (I assume that you also see the static variables as global as you show them in your code snippet)

Comment: Regarding the uint32t and uint8_t variable sees "uint32_t EE_lifetime" and "uint8_t  EE_dummy"  as type of the variable EEMEM, resulting in one variable combining their documentation (and ignoring the second type).

Comment: Thank you albert - EXTRACT_STATIC was set to NO. This was the reason this variables where not documented. With EXTRACT_STATIC = YES they are listed correct. I assumed doxygen extracts global variables sensitiv by context - this was not clear for me.

But the problem with the variables of the type EEMEM is still existant.
I tried to define this variables additional as static - this is accepted by the compiler - but they are still listed wrong.

Comment: I don't know avr-gcc, but as far as I know in C (and C++) in case of a construct line 'uint8_t  EE_dummy EEMEM' the data type is 'uint8_t  EE_dummy' and the variable is ' EEMEM' this all without using include files. From the svr site I learned that" #define EEMEM   __attribute__((section(".eeprom"))) and as far as I know __attribute__ is not seen as something special by doxygen, so in this case it would be something like a function (when expanding it). Best is to move EEMEM before the variable name, when possible, or define EEMEM to an empty string. See also __stdcall in the manual.

Comment: That's it - thank you again! I didn't realize that it is possible to write the attribute EEMEM in front of the variable name, because everyone write it beyond it. Now "uint8_t  EEMEM EE_Dummy" is extracted correct in doxygen. All problems are solved.

Answer (score 0):

You can tell `doxygen` to ignore the `EEMEM` (and `PROGMEM` while you're at it) C preprocessor macros by adding the following lines to your `Doxyfile`:

```
PREDEFINED += EEMEM:=
PREDEFINED += PROGMEM:=
```

Then `doxygen` will read your code line

```
uint32_t EE_lifetime EEMEM = 0; ///< overall time in use
```

as

```
uint32_t EE_lifetime = 0; ///< overall time in use
```

which produces the expected documentation for `EE_lifetime`.